# spring + hibernate 405 delete method not supported

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I access this function via  http://localhost:8080/cerebromodel/api/skillChecklists/staff/{4}/checklist/{1}
I get 405.

```
//delete custom
    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove/staff/{sid}/checklist/{cid}", method = DELETE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteStaffChecklist(@PathVariable Long sid,@PathVariable Long cid) throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            StaffSkillChecklist ssc = staffSkillChecklistRepository.deleteStaffChecklist(sid, cid);
            staffSkillChecklistRepository.delete(ssc.getId());
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            // todo: dig exception, most likely org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }
    }
```

What is missing?

Comment: Maybe you mistyped it, but the URL you posted is missing the "remove" while it's there in your code. That could definitely cause a 405 error.

Comment: Thank u Tim...My url was incorrect..cant believe myself

Answer (score 1):

Your accessing link is `http://localhost:8080/cerebromodel/api/skillChecklists/staff/{4}/checklist/{1}`

while handler have URL mentioned as

```
/remove/staff/{sid}/checklist/{cid}
```

**missing remove**  in your accessing link.